# Trigger webhook when Google Sheet edited

Tags: google-docs, webhooks, google-docs-api

I made a google sheet for sharing todo list with co-workers.

My hope is when that sheet is modified, send message to slack channel.

Even if tried to find api related with this, I failed to suitable one.

Is there a appropriate API or webhook?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's Drive API's [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) which lets you watch for changes to resources. You can also use Apps Scripts' [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) trigger which acts more like a real-time checker.

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

This [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Ht5WL35T9EI;context-place=forum/docs) might also offer additional insight.