# Is there a way by which I can send slack messages from google sheets based on a condition?

Tags: google-sheets, slack, google-workspace, gsuite-addons

I want to send messages to slack users in my workspace from a google sheet whenever a condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing this but Zapier may work for you? https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations/slack

Alternatively something like [Trigger webhook when Google Sheet edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690332/trigger-webhook-when-google-sheet-edited) could work where you create a Slack webhook - https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks